# Application deployment MAC OS X

Tags: macos

Здравствуйте, друзья админы!

Поздравляю вас с наступающим Новым Годом!

Не могли бы вы мне подсказать, есть ли способ удаленного управления установкой/удалением приложений с MAC OS Server X? Т.е. в инфраструктуре имеются MAC-Books, iMacs и прочие прелести от Apple. Хотелось бы получить полный контроль над установленными приложениями.

Спасибо за информацию!

Answer (score 1):

Осмелюсь предположить, что как и на большинстве unix-like систем puppet или chef помогут тебе